# Retrieve Injection Members from Unity Container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am doing some dependency injection with Microsoft.Practices.Unity.

For some classes, I am using injection factories like this:

```
 container.RegisterType<ICar>(new InjectionFactory(o => {return new Car("Toyota")}));
```

Later in my code, I want to be able to find out if I have used or not an injection factory for a given interface.

I see that I can get regitrations in container.Registrations, but these objects do not give me injection members.

A possible way to get them would be to implement a wrapper around my IUnityContainer, that records the injection members.

But maybe there is some better way that directly leverages unity API ? Is there a way to get these injection members directly from the unity container ?

Comment: should you not just inject them into the constructor?

Comment: Can you please explain why do you need this feature?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how I can automatically test that my dependency graph is 'well formed', that is to say, each mapped type can be constructed. In order to construct a type properly, it either needs to be created with injection factory, or have all of its parameters in largest constructor registered in unity.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in my comment (but not with unity). Just copied it from my project.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var lgr = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        var logger = new NlogLogger(lgr);

        services.AddSingleton<ILogger>(provider => logger);
        services.AddSingleton<IMachineConfigFactory, MachineConfigFactory>();
        services.AddSingleton<IMemoryCacheService, MemoryCacheService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IServerManagerService, ServerManagerService>();
        services.AddSingleton<ISubscriberServerHubService, SubscriberServerHubService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IPurgeService, PurgeService>();

        var configuration = GetConfiguration(option);
        services.AddSingleton(configuration);

        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<HostConfig>(configuration.GetSection("HostConfig"));

        services.AddSingleton<ServerManager>();
        services.AddSingleton<CacheManagerService>();

        return services;
    }
```

and then:

```
 public class HealthChecker : IHealthChecker
{
    private readonly HealthCheckerConfig _config;
    private readonly IAssetProvider _assetProvider;

    public HealthChecker(IOptions<HealthCheckerConfig> config, IAssetProvider assetProvider)
    {
        _config = config.Value;
        _assetProvider = assetProvider;
    }
}
```

or am i missing something?